# Como pasar una consulta My SQL de join a subconsulta

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo esta consulta sql donde se utiliza join para resolverla, pero me piden que la misma consulta se realize utilizando subconsultas. Me podrian ayudar por favor.
Estructura de las tablas usadas:

Tabla participante

```
id_participante: INT (11) NOT NULL PK
dni_participante: VARCHAR (10) 
apellido: VARCHAR (20) 
nombre: VARCHAR (20) 
dirección: VARCHAR (35) 
edad: INT (11) 
telefono: VARCHAR (35) 
sexo: VARCHAR (35)
```

Tabla categoria

```
id_categoria : INT (11) NOT NULL PK
nombre_cat: VARCHAR (35) 
edad_min: INT (11) 
edad_max: INT (11) 
sexo: VARCHAR (35)
```

Tabla inscripcion

```
id_inscripcion: INT (11) NOT NULL PK
fecha_insc: FECHA 
abono_inscrip: DOBLE 
id_participante: INT (11) FK
id_categoria: INT (11) FK
```

Consulta con inner join:

```
SELECT 
participante.nombre, participante.apellido 
FROM participante 
INNER JOIN inscripcion 
ON participante.id_participante = inscripcion.id_participante 
INNER JOIN categoria 
ON inscripcion.id_categoria = categoria.id_categoria 
WHERE nombre_cat = "Damas B";
```

Lo que probe hacer fueron estas dos consultas por separado

```
SELECT nombre, apellido FROM participante WHERE id_participante IN (SELECT id_participante FROM inscripcion)
```

```
SELECT id_categoria FROM inscripcion WHERE id_categoria IN (SELECT id_categoria FROM categoria WHERE nombre_cat="Damas B")
```

Pero no se como utilizar subconsultas para consultar las 3 tablas.

Comment: Intentaste algo? Alguna cosa? Probaste alguna forma de cambiarla? Cuál es el problema con modificarla?

Comment: Es importante que conste en la pregunta si se trata de un ejercicio. Lo digo porque de otro modo no tendría sentido pasar una consulta basada en `JOIN` a sub-consultas. ¿Es un ejercicio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aclarando que Cedano tiene razón con su comentario (no tienen ningún sentido pasar esto a subconsultas) y que ya lo resolviste, solo te falta ordenarlo

```
SELECT id_categoria 
FROM inscripcion 
WHERE id_categoria IN (SELECT id_categoria FROM categoria WHERE nombre_cat="Damas B")
```

esto devuelve la lista de categorías que queres... pero si esta tabla ya lista el nombre de participantes, entonces lo podes arreglar mucho mejor

```
SELECT id_participante 
FROM inscripcion 
WHERE id_categoria IN (SELECT id_categoria FROM categoria WHERE nombre_cat="Damas B")
```

Si a tu otra consulta le agregamos esta como filtro, nos queda:

```
SELECT nombre, apellido 
FROM participante WHERE id_participante IN 
    (SELECT id_participante 
    FROM inscripcion 
    WHERE id_categoria IN (SELECT id_categoria FROM categoria WHERE nombre_cat="Damas B"))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @gbianchi, era lo que necesitaba, te agradezco mucho :)